# Rails 5 + Heroku: Assets are not loaded in production, but works in localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

> My problem seems like any other classic asset pipeline issues on
>   heroku which are already asked, but none of the solutions worked for
>   me.

**Question:**

How to solve this problem?

**Current Situation:**

I have created a custom layout to include my ***vendor assets***. Below is the code

```
#app/views/layouts/gentellela_theme.html.erb
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>HMS</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "css/custom", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "fullcalendar.print.min", :media => "print", 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "dataTables.bootstrap4.min", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "gentellela_theme", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>

  <body class="nav-md">
    <%= render "layouts/sidenav" %>
    <%= render "layouts/topnav" %>

    <%= yield %>
    <%= render "layouts/footer" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'js/custom', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Problem:**

I have two files under `vendor/assets/components/gentelella/production/js/custom.js` and `vendor/assets/components/gentelella/production/css/custom.css`. These files are loaded and working well in localhost, but they are **not loading in Heroku**

I can only see a warning like below in the browser console, but nothing more. ***No 404 errors either***.

> Loading failed for the  with source
>   “https://boiling-dusk-64956.herokuapp.com/javascripts/js/custom.js”

My `config/application.rb` looks like this

```
require_relative 'boot'

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module HMS
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.
    config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('vendor', 'assets', 'components', 'gentelella', 'production')
  end
end
```

My `config/initializers/assets.rb` looks like this

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

# Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'

# Add additional assets to the asset load path
# Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Emoji.images_path

# Precompile additional assets.
# application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already added.
# Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( fullcalendar.print.min.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css)
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( gentellela_theme.js )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << Proc.new { |path, fn| fn =~ /vendor\/assets\/components\/gentelella\/production/ }
```

So I've referred to the related questions and tried to solve the issue, but to no avail. Below are my failed attempts

**Attempt #1**

Precompiled the assets locally with

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

and pushed the changes to heroku, but the problem persists.

**Attempt #2**

Added the below lines in `config/application.rb`

```
config.assets.enabled = true
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

and pushed the changes to heroku, but the problem persists.

**Attempt #3**

Modified `config.assets.compile = false` to `config.assets.compile = true` in `config/environments/production.rb`, but when pushing to heroku, the push failed with the below error

````
remote:  !     A security vulnerability has been detected in your application.
remote:  !     To protect your application you must take action. Your application
remote:  !     is currently exposing its credentials via an easy to exploit directory
remote:  !     traversal.
remote:  !     
remote:  !     To protect your application you must either upgrade to Sprockets version "3.7.2"
remote:  !     or disable dynamic compilation at runtime by setting:
remote:  !     
remote:  !     ```
remote:  !     config.assets.compile = false # Disables security vulnerability
remote:  !     ```
remote:  !     
remote:  !     To read more about this security vulnerability please refer to this blog post:
remote:  !     https://blog.heroku.com/rails-asset-pipeline-vulnerability
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to boiling-dusk-64956.
````

So, I upgraded the sprockets version as suggested and pushed the changes to heroku. This time the push has succeeded without any errors. Next I've run `heroku run rake assets:precomplie` and restarted the server. But now the application has crashed. Below is the `heroku logs --tail` info

```
2018-09-20T08:27:33.161369+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/departments" host=boiling-dusk-64956.herokuapp.com request_id=fe446dfc-ea7c-4d38-8b6b-ec529e8db9eb fwd="27.7.94.242" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2018-09-20T08:28:34.114593+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=577M(112.7%)
2018-09-20T08:28:34.114685+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2018-09-20T08:29:16.452991+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2018-09-20T08:29:16.452911+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=611M(119.5%)
2018-09-20T08:30:16.740081+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2018-09-20T08:30:16.743963+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2018-09-20T08:30:17.601536+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2018-09-20T08:30:17.631815+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-09-20 08:30:17] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
2018-09-20T08:30:17.631835+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.7/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/server.rb:177:in `select'
2018-09-20T08:30:17.631838+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.7/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/server.rb:177:in `block in start'
2018-09-20T08:30:17.631840+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.7/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/server.rb:33:in `start'
2018-09-20T08:30:17.631843+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:34:in `run'
2018-09-20T08:30:17.631841+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.7/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/server.rb:164:in `start'
2018-09-20T08:30:17.631847+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:79:in `start'
2018-09-20T08:30:17.631845+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/server.rb:297:in `start'
2018-09-20T08:30:17.631851+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
2018-09-20T08:30:17.631849+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:90:in `block in server'
2018-09-20T08:30:17.631853+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
2018-09-20T08:30:17.631856+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
2018-09-20T08:30:17.631859+00:00 app[web.1]: bin/rails:4:in `require'
2018-09-20T08:30:17.631854+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
2018-09-20T08:30:17.697233+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-09-20 08:30:17] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2018-09-20T08:30:17.631860+00:00 app[web.1]: bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2018-09-20T08:30:17.632626+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-09-20 08:30:17] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2018-09-20T08:30:19.862800+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-09-20T08:30:17.637116 #4]  INFO -- : [fe446dfc-ea7c-4d38-8b6b-ec529e8db9eb] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 194442ms (ActiveRecord: 2.6ms)
2018-09-20T08:30:19.862814+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-09-20T08:30:17.643023 #4] FATAL -- : [fe446dfc-ea7c-4d38-8b6b-ec529e8db9eb]
2018-09-20T08:30:19.862817+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-09-20T08:30:17.643123 #4] FATAL -- : [fe446dfc-ea7c-4d38-8b6b-ec529e8db9eb] ActionView::Template::Error ():
2018-09-20T08:30:19.862820+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-09-20T08:30:17.647307 #4] FATAL -- : [fe446dfc-ea7c-4d38-8b6b-ec529e8db9eb]     3:    <head>
2018-09-20T08:30:19.862822+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-09-20T08:30:17.647399 #4] FATAL -- : [fe446dfc-ea7c-4d38-8b6b-ec529e8db9eb]     4:      <title>HMS</title>
2018-09-20T08:30:19.862824+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-09-20T08:30:17.647458 #4] FATAL -- : [fe446dfc-ea7c-4d38-8b6b-ec529e8db9eb]     5:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
2018-09-20T08:30:19.862826+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-09-20T08:30:17.647517 #4] FATAL -- : [fe446dfc-ea7c-4d38-8b6b-ec529e8db9eb]     6:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag "css/custom", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
2018-09-20T08:30:19.862829+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-09-20T08:30:17.647561 #4] FATAL -- : [fe446dfc-ea7c-4d38-8b6b-ec529e8db9eb]     7:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag "fullcalendar.print.min", :media => "print", 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
2018-09-20T08:30:19.862831+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-09-20T08:30:17.647604 #4] FATAL -- : [fe446dfc-ea7c-4d38-8b6b-ec529e8db9eb]     8:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag "dataTables.bootstrap4.min", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
2018-09-20T08:30:19.862833+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-09-20T08:30:17.647647 #4] FATAL -- : [fe446dfc-ea7c-4d38-8b6b-ec529e8db9eb]     9:      <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
2018-09-20T08:30:19.862835+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-09-20T08:30:17.647690 #4] FATAL -- : [fe446dfc-ea7c-4d38-8b6b-ec529e8db9eb]
2018-09-20T08:30:19.862838+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-09-20T08:30:17.647732 #4] FATAL -- : [fe446dfc-ea7c-4d38-8b6b-ec529e8db9eb] app/views/layouts/gentellela_theme.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_layouts_gentellela_theme_html_erb___843058433631945669_70285598017940'
2018-09-20T08:30:19.862840+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-09-20T08:30:17.657292 #4]  INFO -- : [ab0d5f1c-d91e-4741-825e-97e1ce5443cf] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 271041ms (ActiveRecord: 38.3ms)
2018-09-20T08:30:19.862841+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-09-20T08:30:17.676144 #4] FATAL -- : [ab0d5f1c-d91e-4741-825e-97e1ce5443cf]
2018-09-20T08:30:19.862843+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-09-20T08:30:17.676296 #4] FATAL -- : [ab0d5f1c-d91e-4741-825e-97e1ce5443cf] ActionView::Template::Error ():
2018-09-20T08:30:19.862845+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-09-20T08:30:17.679494 #4] FATAL -- : [ab0d5f1c-d91e-4741-825e-97e1ce5443cf]     3:    <head>
2018-09-20T08:30:19.862847+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-09-20T08:30:17.679561 #4] FATAL -- : [ab0d5f1c-d91e-4741-825e-97e1ce5443cf]     4:      <title>HMS</title>
2018-09-20T08:30:19.862848+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-09-20T08:30:17.679834 #4] FATAL -- : [ab0d5f1c-d91e-4741-825e-97e1ce5443cf]     5:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
2018-09-20T08:30:19.862850+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-09-20T08:30:17.679898 #4] FATAL -- : [ab0d5f1c-d91e-4741-825e-97e1ce5443cf]     6:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag "css/custom", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
2018-09-20T08:30:19.862852+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-09-20T08:30:17.680159 #4] FATAL -- : [ab0d5f1c-d91e-4741-825e-97e1ce5443cf]     7:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag "fullcalendar.print.min", :media => "print", 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
2018-09-20T08:30:19.862853+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-09-20T08:30:17.680220 #4] FATAL -- : [ab0d5f1c-d91e-4741-825e-97e1ce5443cf]     8:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag "dataTables.bootstrap4.min", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
2018-09-20T08:30:19.862855+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-09-20T08:30:17.680277 #4] FATAL -- : [ab0d5f1c-d91e-4741-825e-97e1ce5443cf]     9:      <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
2018-09-20T08:30:19.862857+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-09-20T08:30:17.683960 #4] FATAL -- : [ab0d5f1c-d91e-4741-825e-97e1ce5443cf]
2018-09-20T08:30:19.862859+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-09-20T08:30:17.684030 #4] FATAL -- : [ab0d5f1c-d91e-4741-825e-97e1ce5443cf] app/views/layouts/gentellela_theme.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_layouts_gentellela_theme_html_erb___843058433631945669_70285598017940'
2018-09-20T08:30:19.862861+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2018-09-20T08:30:20.300416+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2018-09-20T08:30:26.455831+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 51256 -e production`
2018-09-20T08:30:32.965279+00:00 app[web.1]: The PGconn, PGresult, and PGError constants are deprecated, and will be
2018-09-20T08:30:32.965301+00:00 app[web.1]: removed as of version 1.0.
2018-09-20T08:30:32.965303+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-09-20T08:30:32.965305+00:00 app[web.1]: You should use PG::Connection, PG::Result, and PG::Error instead, respectively.
2018-09-20T08:30:32.965306+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-09-20T08:30:32.965309+00:00 app[web.1]: Called from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
2018-09-20T08:30:33.458524+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-09-20 08:30:33] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2018-09-20T08:30:33.458570+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-09-20 08:30:33] INFO  ruby 2.3.7 (2018-03-28) [x86_64-linux]
2018-09-20T08:30:33.459164+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-09-20 08:30:33] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=4 port=51256
2018-09-20T08:30:33.797414+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
```

So, I'm unable to detect why the application has crashed. Am I on the right track to solve my problem? Any help is appreciated. TIA

**Update #1:**

I got my app running and followed **@Maxence** approach. Now I can see *404* error messages for both the files

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/stylesheets/css/custom.css") 

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/javascripts/js/custom.js")
```

**Update #2:**

The logical paths for those files from `sprockets-manifest` file are below

```
gentelella/production/js/custom.js
```

and

```
gentelella/production/css/custom.css
```

Comment: But as per your logs, `Memory quota exceeded` something is causing a spike.

Comment: Yes the memory thing looks very suspicious

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well I have had quite a few problems with asset pipeline in production like you.

First : Dont compile assets at Heroku. Whether you do through the CLI `heroku run rake assets:precomplie` or through your production file `config.assets.compile = true`. It has not worked for me either.

Just use the recommended `config.assets.compile = false`. It will also make your deploy much faster because everything has been precompiled locally and your slug will be slimmer too.

So basically just do a `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` locally. This will create fingerprinted assets in your `public/assets` folder. It will also create a `.sprockets-manifest` file in this folder.

`sprockets_manifest` is the table of correspondence between your fingerprinted assets and the non fingerprinted assets referred to by the application helpers `image_tag` etc .. (You can open the manifest file, it is very interesting and helped me understand the problems I had)

Now you should be able to see all your assets fingerprinted in the `public/assets` folder. If some are missing you should check your `assets.rb` file and make sure you have included all files you need. (Precompiling method only precompiles what is mentionned in this file)

Basically from now on, your app is fine though I have found a few things that could prevent a good matching of assets by the manifest file / sprockets :

- in your helpers, always mention the file type `image_tag(splash)` should be changed to `image_tag(splash.jpg)`. It is because your manifest file adds the file type to the logical path, and rails doesn't guess it automagically. You should do the same with `javascript_include_tag "gentellela_theme"` and change it to `javascript_include_tag "gentellela_theme.js"`. Or `javascript_include_tag 'js/custom'` to `javascript_include_tag 'js/custom.js'`
- If you use SASS make sure your css files are properly named `whatever.css.scss` and not `whatever.scss`. I am using sass helpers in my css files and my files bad naming was breaking the matching by the manifest.

Then you should be good

EDIT

As per comments below, if you have changed the assets name with full name+file type (`splash` changed to `splash.jpg` for example) and the file is still not showing. Check the logical path of that specific asset in the manifest file. And replace the name of the asset by the logical path. The logical path disambiguates asset names.

EDIT 2

This thread aonly concernes Sprockets 3.X. Sprockets 4 / Webpacker works differently

Comment: Thank you for the response. I got my app running and after when I tried your approach, but still the error persists. Now I see 404 error messages for both `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/stylesheets/css/custom.css")` and `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/javascripts/js/custom.js")`

Comment: Why do you have routes pointing to assets ? Can you show the code that triggers this error ?

Comment: Those are the errors that get triggered when Rails doesn't found the assets in the location that it is searching.

Comment: Try renaming your helper like this : `javascript_include_tag 'custom.js'`

Comment: You mean without the `js/`?

Comment: yes. This is maybe the problem. Though I don't know why it considers the link as a route ...

Comment: No luck. That failed in the localhost itself.

Comment: Can you post the bit of code related to this error ? Because when you add a link to a stylesheet, it is not an application route, so this is strange you get this error. What could happen is that the link is not pointing to your asset, then your asset appears broken. Nothing else much

Comment: The code is already there. Specifically these lines `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "css/custom", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>` and `<%= javascript_include_tag 'js/custom', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>`. As I said earlier rails will trigger such errors when the assets are not found in the location it is looking for.

Comment: Ok. Open the manifest `public/assets/sprockets-manifest...` and try to find `custom.js`. If you find it what is the logical path you can see ?

Comment: Ok, try replacing the path you have originally set with the logical path : `stylesheet_link_tag "css/custom", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track"` to be replaced by `stylesheet_link_tag "gentelella/production/css/custom.css", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track"`

Comment: Actually because this file is in the header, it would be better to add it to the `applications.css` file so that it is pre compiled into the css master file `application.css` : `*= require gentelella/production/css/custom.css`

Comment: Ah, It worked, but why just `css/custom.css` and `css/custom.js` didn't worked on production but worked in local? Anyways update your answer with that comment, I will accept it :)

Comment: Well Sprockets is less magical than the rails app and needs be more explicit. (in development, if I am not mistaken, Sprockets is not used) Although all CSS and JS that is appwide should be included in the master file as explained above. It is slightly faster.

Comment: Was struggling with this for months, but your trick on adding .png to the helper name solved my woes! Thanks so much my friend.

Comment: I am getting this error ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/users/assets/application.js")

Answer (score 1):

With all the correct config I was having this same issue (using heroku config that comes with the thoughtbot/suspenders gem) because I was using `url` instead of `image-url` in my css.

I had to change references in my css to set background images like this:

```css
.my-div {
  background-image: image-url('some-image.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}
```

And my deployed app loaded the images from the `app/assets/images` directory the same as on localhost.

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps anyone else, my issue ended up being that I was using absolute paths rather than the Rails asset URL helpers... i.e., I was doing stuff like this:

`src="/assets/script.js"`

`href="/assets/image.png"`

`background-image: url('/assets/image.png');`

`@font-face { src: url('/assets/FontName'); font-family: ...`

rather than:

`src="<%= asset_url('script.js') %>"`

`background-image: asset_url('image.png');`

etc.

To my understanding, this fix works because it tells Heroku how to find the *precompiled* assets in `public/assets`, which all include a computed "fingerprint"/digest appended to the file name. The original assets that you put in `/assets/images` or wherever aren't actually loaded by Heroku, because it's already got those precompiled files.

...This probably would have been obvious to someone with more experience, but I'm still fairly new at this. ;)