# Heroku deploy failing for rails5 app due to "precompiling assets failed"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, assets, pipeline, precompile

Running `git push heroku master` kicks off the deploy process, but it seems to hang during the following phase:

```
remote:        Fetching sass-rails 5.0.7
remote:        Installing sass-rails 5.0.7
```

Finally it tells me that precompiling assets has failed.

I feel like I've tried everything to get this to work.  I'm on my 3rd week of spinning my tires trying to get the app to deploy.  For reference, here is the repo:  https://github.com/mkrul/factory-ops

```
remote:        Post-install message from sass:
remote:        
remote:        Ruby Sass is deprecated and will be unmaintained as of 26 March 2019.
remote:        
remote:        * If you use Sass as a command-line tool, we recommend using Dart Sass, the new
remote:          primary implementation: https://sass-lang.com/install
remote:        
remote:        * If you use Sass as a plug-in for a Ruby web framework, we recommend using the
remote:          sassc gem: https://github.com/sass/sassc-ruby#readme
remote:        
remote:        * For more details, please refer to the Sass blog:
remote:          http://sass.logdown.com/posts/7081811
remote:        
remote:        Removing bundler (1.15.2)
remote:        Bundle completed (162.24s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote:        The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.
remote: -----> Installing node-v10.14.1-linux-x64
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        Yarn executable was not detected in the system.
remote:        Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        Uglifier::Error: Unexpected token: name (rails)
remote:        /tmp/build_515c8a50b0ac85c4870b659697d0fa8b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/uglifier-4.1.20/lib/uglifier.rb:234:in `parse_result'
remote:        /tmp/build_515c8a50b0ac85c4870b659697d0fa8b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/uglifier-4.1.20/lib/uglifier.rb:216:in `run_uglifyjs'
remote:        /tmp/build_515c8a50b0ac85c4870b659697d0fa8b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/uglifier-4.1.20/lib/uglifier.rb:168:in `compile'
remote:        /tmp/build_515c8a50b0ac85c4870b659697d0fa8b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/compressing.rb:65:in `block in js_compressor='
remote:        /tmp/build_515c8a50b0ac85c4870b659697d0fa8b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy_proc_processor.rb:31:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_515c8a50b0ac85c4870b659697d0fa8b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
remote:        /tmp/build_515c8a50b0ac85c4870b659697d0fa8b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_515c8a50b0ac85c4870b659697d0fa8b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
remote:        /tmp/build_515c8a50b0ac85c4870b659697d0fa8b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_515c8a50b0ac85c4870b659697d0fa8b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
remote:        /tmp/build_515c8a50b0ac85c4870b659697d0fa8b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
remote:        /tmp/build_515c8a50b0ac85c4870b659697d0fa8b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
remote:        /tmp/build_515c8a50b0ac85c4870b659697d0fa8b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_515c8a50b0ac85c4870b659697d0fa8b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
remote:        /tmp/build_515c8a50b0ac85c4870b659697d0fa8b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_515c8a50b0ac85c4870b659697d0fa8b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_515c8a50b0ac85c4870b659697d0fa8b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
remote:        /tmp/build_515c8a50b0ac85c4870b659697d0fa8b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:142:in `block in find'
remote:        /tmp/build_515c8a50b0ac85c4870b659697d0fa8b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_515c8a50b0ac85c4870b659697d0fa8b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:228:in `block in stat_tree'
remote:        /tmp/build_515c8a50b0ac85c4870b659697d0fa8b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:212:in `block in stat_directory'
remote:        /tmp/build_515c8a50b0ac85c4870b659697d0fa8b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_515c8a50b0ac85c4870b659697d0fa8b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `stat_directory'
remote:        /tmp/build_515c8a50b0ac85c4870b659697d0fa8b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:227:in `stat_tree'
remote:        /tmp/build_515c8a50b0ac85c4870b659697d0fa8b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_515c8a50b0ac85c4870b659697d0fa8b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_515c8a50b0ac85c4870b659697d0fa8b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_515c8a50b0ac85c4870b659697d0fa8b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_515c8a50b0ac85c4870b659697d0fa8b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:140:in `find'
remote:        /tmp/build_515c8a50b0ac85c4870b659697d0fa8b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:186:in `compile'
remote:        /tmp/build_515c8a50b0ac85c4870b659697d0fa8b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:68:in `block (3 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_515c8a50b0ac85c4870b659697d0fa8b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
remote:        /tmp/build_515c8a50b0ac85c4870b659697d0fa8b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:67:in `block (2 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_515c8a50b0ac85c4870b659697d0fa8b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to bar-and-pub-supply.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/bar-and-pub-supply.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```

**UPDATE 4/6/8:40PM EST**

After changing my `sass-file` gem and changing my production.rb config file, I ran `RAILS_ENV=production bin/rails assets:precompile`, and received the following error:

```
[1/5] Validating package.json...
[2/5] Resolving packages...
success Nothing to install.
success Saved lockfile.
Done in 0.18s.
rails aborted!
Uglifier::Error: Unexpected token: name (rails)
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/uglifier-4.1.20/lib/uglifier.rb:234:in `parse_result'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/uglifier-4.1.20/lib/uglifier.rb:216:in `run_uglifyjs'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/uglifier-4.1.20/lib/uglifier.rb:168:in `compile'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/compressing.rb:65:in `block in js_compressor='
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy_proc_processor.rb:31:in `call'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:142:in `block in find'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in logical_paths'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:228:in `block in stat_tree'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:212:in `block in stat_directory'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `each'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `stat_directory'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:227:in `stat_tree'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:140:in `find'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:186:in `compile'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:68:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:67:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:23:in `block in perform'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `perform'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
/home/mkrul/Desktop/projects/cloned_factory_ops/factory-ops/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
/home/mkrul/Desktop/projects/cloned_factory_ops/factory-ops/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
mkrul@mkrul-ThinkPad-T440s:~/Desktop/projects/cloned_factory_ops/factory-ops$ 
mkrul@mkrul-ThinkPad-T440s:~/Desktop/projects/cloned_factory_ops/factory-ops$ RAILS_ENV=production bin/rails assets:precompileRAILS_ENV=production bin/rails assets:precompile
rails aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'assets:precompileRAILS_ENV=production' (See the list of available tasks with `rake --tasks`)
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:23:in `block in perform'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `perform'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
/home/mkrul/Desktop/projects/cloned_factory_ops/factory-ops/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
/home/mkrul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
/home/mkrul/Desktop/projects/cloned_factory_ops/factory-ops/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Try precompiling assets locally before you push, and see if you can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yeah I think that was the first thing I tried, with no luck :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you get Heroku to return  `Don't know how to build task 'assets:precompileRAILS_ENV=production' (See the list of available tasks with rake --tasks)` ?

Usually this command : `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` is to be done locally in your console. It allows you to compile your assets locally.

Also by doing it locally you may get some information about the file that can't be precompiled. And then try to debug this file. It is either a javascript or a CSS file.

Some possible errors :

- Js files including ES6 => then you have to use Harmony as advised by
  Mark
- Some dynamic content (if you have css.erb or js.erb files)
- Some    typo in a JS file (CSS typos trigger warnings all the time)
- ..

Comment: Ok when I look at your repo, first js file (application.js), your require are not commented: `require rails-ujs` try writing instead: `//= require rails-ujs` instead

Comment: I mean by "commented" adding `//= ` before your requires... This will not comment your requires but just use the right syntax for them to be properly accounted for.

Comment: Aaah, that was it!  The requires needed to be commented out.  Ran the precompile step manually and then deployed with no problems!  Thank you!!

I guess I hadn't thought to comment out the `require` lines because it made sense to leave them uncommented... otherwise how would they be read by the machine?  Thank you so much for your assistance!!

Comment: You may also read this answer I made about asset pipeline some time ago : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52421137/rails-5-heroku-assets-are-not-loaded-in-production-but-works-in-localhost/52423496#52423496 It will help you understand what precompiling does and maybe fix further issues you can encounter later. (development environment is globally more flexible than production as it does not use precompiling to display assets)

Answer (score 1):

There could be a couple different reasons for this.

First, as Heroku is warning you of...use `sassc` instead of `sass-rails`...so replace `gem sass-rails` in your gemfile with `gem 'sassc-rails'`

Second, try adding the following to your `config/environments/production.rb` file (which will replace `config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier`..

```
config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(harmony: true)
```

Comment: Okay.. made both of those suggested changes, and unfortunately it didn't work, but I'm getting a totally different error now.   Going to update the original post shortly.  Thank you for helping to troubleshoot this.