# why am i getting this routing error? ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/toastr.js.map"):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I'm seeing this on localhost and prod:

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/toastr.js.map"):

I've tried including toastr.js.map in my manifest file: no luck. Also tried renaming the file to toastr.map.js - which immediately started throwing js errors in the console.

Is there a way to either automatically generate map files or ignore them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across a similar problem recently. The way I solved it was by going inside the manifest file (e.g., `public/assets/.sprockets-manifest-[md5hash].json`, finding the logical names of the asset files and using those instead of the absolute paths.

In my case, the fix was to remove the `/assets/` prefix from the `javascript_include_tag`.

In particular, in my html files I replaced this...

```
= javascript_include_tag "/assets/admin/events/index.js"
```

...with this...

```
= javascript_include_tag "admin/events/index.js"
```

...and recompiled assets. This seemed to do the trick for me.

Here's a reference to the thread where I found this solution:
[Rails 5 + Heroku: Assets are not loaded in production, but works in localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52421137/rails-5-heroku-assets-are-not-loaded-in-production-but-works-in-localhost)